# CSS align images inside div

Tags: html, css

Hello guys i have main div tag: height:1800px; width:1200px; inside it there are div with two images h:1800px and w:100px. I want to first align one top and right and second top and left inside Main div.

I tried this:

```
    #LeftFull{ position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;}

#RightFull{ position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;}
```

but its working in body not Main div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that to work then you'll need to position the div, as well. Absolute position doesn't work without a parent that isn't positioned. I would either use relative instead or position the div with relative.

```
    #LeftFull{ position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;}

#RightFull{ position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;}

#div{ position:relative;}
```

That should make your images position themselves around the div, instead of the body of your page.

Comment: Good guy :D I will mark as accepted answer in 8 minutes :) And how i can move Main Div in center?

Comment: @acid `div.main {margin: 0 auto; width: 90%}`

Comment: If you have <center> tags around it I don't think relative would affect it... Yeah, it should still be centered as long as you don't try to position it with left, right, top, or bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with `float` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dafastestfingers/j2Lkm/1/)